# having issue with Table creation in SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having problem while table creation. Error says no such table even my query is correct and working fine I have checked it many times.

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int database_version = 1;
    public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE"+TableData.TABLE_NAME+"("+TableData.USER_NAME+" TEXT, "+TableData.USER_PASS+" TEXT);";

    public DatabaseOperations(Context context) {
        super(context,TableData.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "Database Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database Operations", "Table Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

here is Logcat:

```
08-08 18:00:19.008    2036-2043/com.example.fani.sqlitetest W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 12.494ms
08-08 18:00:19.667    2036-2036/com.example.fani.sqlitetest D/Database Operations﹕ Database Created
08-08 18:00:19.673    2036-2036/com.example.fani.sqlitetest E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: users_info
08-08 18:00:19.679    2036-2036/com.example.fani.sqlitetest E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting user_pass=fani user_name=farhan
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: users_info (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO users_info(user_pass,user_name) VALUES (?,?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not right. There is no space between the `CREATE TABLE` and the table Name.

Try this:

```
String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+TableData.TABLE_NAME+" ("+TableData.USER_NAME+" TEXT, "+TableData.USER_PASS+" TEXT);";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
private static final String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE "+TableData.TABLE_NAME+" ("+TableData.USER_NAME+" TEXT, "+TableData.USER_PASS+" TEXT, "+")";
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.